# Splitting of the conformal group into $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and other factorizations

Tags: lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, conformal-maps

In 1+1 dimensions of Minkowski spacetime, the conformal group can be split into two copies of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acting on null lines. I'm curious to know if a similar split exists for the conformal group in 2+1 or 3+1 dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar split"? 1+1 have very special structure. Certainly in higher dimensions the set of null vectors do not arise from finite union of subspaces. The conformal group of $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$ can be specified in terms of well-known groups (see, e.g. _A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory_ by Schottenloher, chapter 2).